# Terraform missing map element

Tags: terraform

Attempts to map the result from the SQL query. This seems correct to me, but terraform returns an error.

It does not return any blank result for IP and server name.

Is there a bug somewhere? It seems correct to me.

I have main.tf

```
/*
 * admin database
 */

module "sql-servers-admindb" {
  source = "../terraform-modules/terraform-data-db"

  dbtype = "mysql"
  connection = {
    mysql = {
      host  = local.mysql-admin_credentials.dbhost
      user  = local.mysql-admin_credentials.dbuser
      pass  = local.mysql-admin_credentials.dbpass
      dbase = local.mysql-admin_credentials.dbname
    }
    sqlite = null
  }

   debugfile = "debug.json"

 
  query = {
    sqlquery = <<EOT
SELECT sd.serwer_id, sd.ip_local, sd.host_mysql
    FROM serwer_panel sd
    JOIN serwer_serwer_grupa ssg ON ssg.serwer_id = sd.serwer_id 
    JOIN serwer_grupa sg ON ssg.serwer_grupa_id = sg.id
EOT
  }
}


module "terraform-sql" {
  source = "../terraform-modules/terraform-sql"
  depends_on = [module.sql-servers-admindb]
  for_each = { for sql in module.sql-servers-admindb.result.sqlquery : sql.serwer_id => sql }
  general = { 
     zone = "sql.${var.dns_local_name[local.environment]}."
     ptr_networks = "${var.dns_local_reverse_allowed[local.environment]}"
  }
}
```

terraform-modules/terraform-sql/main.tf

```
// IP address and A record
module "sql-nsrecord_a" {
  source       = "../terraform-modules/terraform-generic-nsrecord
  zone         = "{var.general.zone}."
  name         = "${var.sql.serwer_id}."
  type         = "A"
  records      = [var.sql.local_ip]
  ptr_networks = var.general.ptr_networks
}
```

```
/*
 * General
 */

variable "general" {
  type = object({
    zone    = string
    ptr_networks = list(any)
  })
  default = {
    zone  = ""
    ptr_networks  = []
  }
}


/*
 * SQL records
 */

variable "sql" {
  type    = map(any)
  default = {}
}
```

Example debug.json

```
Array
(
    [sqlquery] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [serwer_id] => s12
                    [ip_local] => 127.0.0.1
                    [host_mysql] => 
                )
```

Return error:

```
│ Error: Missing map element
│ 
│   on ../terraform-modules/terraform-sql/main.tf line 9, in module "sql-nsrecord_a":
│    9:   name         = "${var.sql.serwer_id}."
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.sql is empty map of dynamic
│ 
│ This map does not have an element with the key "serwer_id".
╵


╷
│ Error: Missing map element
│ 
│   on ../terraform-modules/terraform-sql/main.tf line 11, in module "sql-nsrecord_a":
│   11:   records      = [var.sql.local_ip]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.sql is empty map of dynamic
│
```

I am asking for advice on how to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be passing the variable `sql` to the `terraform-sql` module and thus its default value is used:

```
  default = {}
```

Hence an empty map. No wonder it doesn't contain some entry.

You need to amend your

```
module "terraform-sql" {
...
}
```

to pass the `sql` argument too.